# Cordova -Angular JS app Reachability check

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an android app using cordova and 
Angular JS.I am facing a critical issue now.
I am using

> navigator.Online

method and its observer methods  like

> document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

to check network connectivity.This is working fine if Wifi is disconnected and connected again.But this same thing is not detecting reachability.i.e If there is Wifi connected and there is no internet then also the navigator methods with return connected or online status.Is there any plugin or methods available to check and monitor reachability of internet like navigator.

Thanks in advance